# How to set UTF-8 in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, aptana3

I have to be able to write the letters å, ä and ö. It works in other program without any problem. But in Aptana I cant do it. Å, ä and ö looks like when I press space on the keyboard.

I go to: 
window->preferences->general->workspace.
It is set to: "Default (cp1252)" and I change it to: "Other UTF-8". 
That dont work!

I rightclick the file in Projectexplorer and set it to "UTF-8" (it's normally set to UTF-8).
That dont work!

In the Edit menu I can see at the bottom there is "Set Encoding", but that is never clickable. It's allways grayed-out.

I have gooooooooogled it but can't find anything that sonds like my problem (some close to but not the same).
Anyone?

Comment: Define "dont work"? How do you verify that the files are not written in UTF-8? And what kind of files do you write?

Comment: well I haven't, but if the file is utf-8 the problem still exists. The problem: "looks like when I press space on the keyboard".

Comment: Oh, so you can type it, but it looks like a space? Maybe the font simply doesn't support non-ASCII characters? That sounds strange, 'though because I'll be hard pressed to think of a common font that doesn't at least support äöü ... Have you tried switching the editor to use another font?

Comment: Ohhhh! I had a font switch. Now I tried Arial and I get my åäö. Thanx for your help. I can use Aptana... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you said, go to `Window->Preferences->General->Workspace`

[image]

Set `Text file encoding` to `Others:UTF-8`, and it just works.

Comment: I accept this as a correct answer. For me the solution was that I did not use a font that had the characters (åäö). However this is a correct answer according to the headline to this thread. I think your answer + this comment is a correct answer for the absolute majority of the people that ends up in this thread.

Comment: @mikael1000 Glad you get it resolved. I thought this answer would never get accepted...